# MongoDB Aggregate Array Length

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, database

I'm working on a simple dev-meet-designer platform, and I am trying to create a better popularity ranking algorithm.

My existing code is:

```
project_collection.aggregate([
        { "$project": { 
            "score": {
              "$divide": [
                "$views",
                { "$divide": [
                    { "$subtract": [ 
                        new Date(), 
                        "$created_at" 
                    ]},
                    10*60*30
                ]}
            ]},
            "created_at": 1,
            "views": 1
        }}
      ], function(error, results) {
          // do stuff
      });
```

I want to switch the code to count the `likers` array from the document, and use that value in place of `$views`. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here's an example document structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53d95d33a3ca780d096e5e7e"),
    "name" : "Foo",
    "tagline" : "This is a test project.",
    "description" : "Foo bar.",
    "tags" : [ 
        "front end"
    ],
    "owner" : "Noah",
    "views" : 2,
    "activity" : [ 
        {
            "options" : {
                "type" : "started",
                "owner" : "Noah"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "options" : {
                "type" : "application",
                "applicant" : "John"
            }
        }
    ],
    "closed" : false,
    "finished" : false,
    "applicants" : [ "John" ],
    "partners" : [],
    "chat" : [],
    "discussion" : [],
    "url" : "",
    "fireQuene" : [],
    "likers" : [ "John", "Noah" ],
    "created_at" : ISODate("2014-07-30T21:01:39.421Z")
}
```

Comment: You should post the document structure in your question to make it more clear. Without it, it's hard to tell how the query should look like.

Comment: If I were to use the code and example document above, the result's JSON would be: `[{"_id" : ObjectId("53d95d33a3ca780d096e5e7e"), "views" : 3, "created_at" : ISODate("2014-07-30T21:01:39.421Z"), "score" : 0.0001253727907694868}]`, @ChristianP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the "array length" as your question asks MongoDB 2.6 introduced the [**`$size`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) operator which returns the length of an array. Used in place of "$views" in your algorithm this would be:

```
project_collection.aggregate([
        { "$project": { 
            "score": {
              "$divide": [
                { "$size": "$likers" },
                { "$divide": [
                    { "$subtract": [ 
                        new Date(), 
                        "$created_at" 
                    ]},
                    10*60*30
                ]}
            ]},
            "created_at": 1,
            "views": 1
        }}
      ], function(error, results) {
          // do stuff
      });
```

If you have an earlier version without this feature then you need to use [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) on the array and [**`$sum`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) to get the count. This you can move into the [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage:

```
project_collection.aggregate([
        { "$unwind": "$likers" },
        { "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "created_at": { "$first": "$created_at" },
            "likers": { "$push": "$likers" },
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }},
        { "$project": {
            "score": {
              "$divide": [
                "$count",
                { "$divide": [
                    { "$subtract": [ 
                        new Date(), 
                        "$created_at" 
                    ]},
                    10*60*30
                ]}
            ]},
            "created_at": 1,
            "views": 1
        }}
      ], function(error, results) {
          // do stuff
      });
```

So `$size` helps you with what you are doing , but otherwise it is generally a good idea to try and keep a "count" of your likers within your document and update that accordingly.